# Creating an SKSpriteNode class with Swift 4

Tags: swift, class, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I've coded a simple game using Swift 4 and XCode, and I've coded everything in the GameScene. All my elements (the monsters, the player, the projectile, etc.) are coded in the GameScene.

I want to transfer my code into dedicated classes (Class Player, class monster, etc.)

I would like to know what the basic structure of a SKSpriteNode class and the call of that class in the GameScene, to be more efficient at adapting my code.

Here's an example of what I've tried :

```
class Vaisseau: SKSpriteNode /*: Creatures */{

var coeur: Int = 0

init(texture: SKTexture, size: CGSize)
{
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}
```

And the initialization in the GameScene :

```
 let player = Vaisseau()
```

Here's how it is actually defined in the GameScene :

```
let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "player")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are declaring your init to have two parameters `(texture: SKTexture, size: CGSize)` but you are not passing the parameters in your initialization call

```
let player = Vaisseau()
```

you either need to change the initialization to...

```
let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
let player = Vaisseau(texture: texture, size: texture.size())
```

and change the init to

```
init(texture: SKTexture, size: CGSize) {
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: size)
}
```

> OR change the init in the class to...

```
init() {
    let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    super.init(texture: texture, color: UIColor.clear, size: texture.size())
}
```

and leave your initialization call as...

```
let player = Vaisseau()
player.position = CGPoint(x: 500, y: 500)
addChild(player)
```

> EDIT added the above 2 lines to show you that those need to be in the scene
>   but other items such as alpha, zPosition, actions, zRotation etc. can be inside of the class

What you need to ask yourself to figure out which one to use is "will the texture for the player ever be different?" if so you may want to consider the first option where you pass in the texture.

Comment: The texture will not be changed, so I'm gonna use the second option.
And should the "addChild(player)"  stay in the function didMove(to view: SKView) from the GameScene ? Because my player element stays in the right bottom corner of the Scene, I was wondering if the position of the addChild was the cause.

Comment: (I can edit the "addChild" code in the post if you need to see it clearly)

Comment: the addChild portion has to stay in the scene (because it is getting added to the scene) likewise you would want to place the positioning in the scene code as well not the class. (see my edit)